# How to customize Contact Form 7 look in smartphone?

Tags: css, mobile

I just checked my site in mobile emulator, and see that Contact Form 7 in my site is not displaying as it should.  Some of the fields are not visible.

I did some research and found this CSS code:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {
.wpcf7-form {
max-width: 500px;
margin: auto;
}}
```

but it doesn't seem to change anything when I check it on the emulator. What is wrong in [my site](http://mobiletest.me/htc_one_emulator/?u=http://deilbeatz.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try Below code, Adjust the width accordingly.

```
@media (max-width:560px)  {
.contact {
  max-width: 280px;
}}
```

Comment: i added, but your code dont change nothing. Check the site in emulator, and will see.

Comment: I copied the page and added this code in responsive.css after @media only screen and (max-width: 400px){ line and it worked, can you please try again.